# Assigning Data to TableLayout Pragmatically Crashes app when launching

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout in XML with a row and three textviews in it. parsing data in table dynamically from an array but when I launch app it crashes.
here is my code

```
TableLayout historyEntries = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.DataTable);
        historyEntries.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        historyEntries.bringToFront();
        for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
            TableRow tr =  (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.datarow);
            TextView c1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            TextView c2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
            TextView c3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
            c1.setText(dataArray[i]);
            c2.setText(String.valueOf(dataArray[i]));
            c3.setText(String.valueOf(dataArray[i]));
            tr.addView(c1);
            tr.addView(c2);
            tr.addView(c3);
            historyEntries.addView(tr);
        }
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can have one and only parent. It is likely that one or all of your views have parent, judging by `findViewById` call. If your views are already inflated in activity, simply drop these lines:

```
tr.addView(c1);
tr.addView(c2);
tr.addView(c3);
historyEntries.addView(tr);
```

Otherwise, you can create a separate layout file with the `TableRow` and the `TextView` if you intend to add more rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_table_row, historyEntries, false);
    TableRow tr =  (TableRow) v.findViewById(R.id.datarow);
    TextView c1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    TextView c2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
    TextView c3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
    c1.setText(dataArray[i]);
    c2.setText(String.valueOf(dataArray[i]));
    c3.setText(String.valueOf(dataArray[i]));
    historyEntries.addView(tr);
}
```

Comment: i did this but after this there is only one entry showing in my table which is the last one in array. there are total 5 entries in my array. i guess it is overwriting data on same row.

Comment: I assume you have only one TableRow in your tablet. If you want to add it dynamically, then create a layout XML file separately, and you can add the view as you did.

Comment: yes you are right there is only one tablerow i created in xml. please can you tell me how can i do that. it will be great help.

Comment: Sure, I've just updated my answer - just take the table row from the table layout, then create a new layout only for the table row.

Comment: View v = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.datatable_row, historyEntries, true);
giving error "Non-static method 'inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @WaqasArshad Sorry that was my bad, it should be `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_table_row, historyEntries, true)`, your `context` can be `getActivity()` too, or `this` if it's an activity.

Comment: got errors "error: class, interface, or enum expected
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {" and alot on "error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void onClick(final View v) {"

Comment: Looks like syntax errors, can you please check your braces..?

Comment: oh sorry one sec.

Comment: <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/DataTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleTxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/>

Comment: only this will be in my mainactivity.xml??

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And make sure your new layout has TableRow as first container.

Comment: well now i have 5 row but data is still in first row rest 4 rows showing nothing

Comment: Can you check if your `dataArray` contains the right data, and no duplicates?

Comment: And also its `v.findViewById`, not just `findViewById`, can you check my answer again?

Comment: String[] dataArray = {
                "Appointment 1",
                "Appointment 2",
                "Appointment 3",
                "Appointment 4",
                "Appointment 5"
        };

Comment: That's weird, sorry I've just updated my answer again, can you please check? Let's see if adding the view explicitly works..